# Send email invite link with NextAuth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Does anyone use NextAuth for their authentication solution? The email provider sign in flow is most straightforward. But I cannot find information on the following: I was wondering how to allow users to send out invite links to add team members (the link will also include information on how to add some parameters, such as permission of this newly invited user specified by the user sending out the invitation)

Comment: So far NextAuth only accounts for login related actions, and the closest you can get is magic links for login. If you want to handle user invitations I think you have to implement this yourself, by having a database where you persist data about user invitations

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using `signIn` like this on click a handler. But, I don't know if this is right.

```
await signIn('email', {
  callbackUrl: '/',
  redirect: false, //so we stay on page
  email: "email.to.invite@example",
});
```

For custom params maybe you should modify `sendVerificationRequest()` https://next-auth.js.org/providers/email#customizing-emails